# How can I make a function called build() have one string input and it returns a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a project that requires me to make a function that takes a string input and return a dictionary.
The string will be consist of a name and a phone number, separated by a comma.

Example of the input: Joe,123-5432 Joe
Example of the output: 123-5432

Comment: Have you tried the `split()` function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
def take_input(x):
   dict={}
   mylist=x.split(',',maxsplit=2)
   dict[mylist[0]]=mylist[1]
   #dict['name']=mylist[0]
   #dict['phone']=mylist[1] output={'name:'Jeo','phone':'123-5432'
   return dict
x=' Joe,123-5432'
print(take_input(x))
```

output=
{' Joe': '123-5432'}

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this:

```
# Function to split a user provided string and delimiter
# And convert it in to a dictionary

def str_to_dict(_user_input_string, _user_provided_delimiter):
    return {_user_input_string.split(_user_provided_delimiter)[0]: _user_input_string.split(_user_provided_delimiter)[-1]}


x = str_to_dict('Joe,123-5432', ',')
print(x, type(x))

#Output
{'Joe': '123-5432'} <class 'dict'>
```